# how to read json response in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

i have a json object in response, using that i have to create a jstree. But not able to read that json object in javascript function.

My JavaScript:

```
var repoId = $('#frmHdnV').val();
// variable to hold request
var request= $.post("CreatJqueryTree",{repoId:repoId},function(data){},"json");

request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){

    alert(response);

    var tem = JSON.parse(response);
    var obj = tem.data;
    $("#tes").jstree({ 
        "json_data" : {
            "data" : // here i need that json object to create this tree
        },
            "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "checkbox", "ui" ]
        }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { alert(data.rslt.obj.data("id")); });

}); 


request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){


    alert("....Not Done...");
    alert(errorThrown);

});
```

the Response i can see in the firefox usinhg firebug. but how to read that json object from response.

Comment: You mean `"json_data" : obj` ?

Comment: You need to replace "data" : // here i need that json object to create this tree by "data": function (n) { return { id: n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0} }

Comment: Your error is that you already specified the datatype as `JSON` therefore you don't need to parse the response - which is probably throwing an error in the console - so you can remove `var tem = JSON.parse(response);` and just use `var obj = response.data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.post("CreatJqueryTree",{repoId:repoId},function(data){
  $("#tes").jstree({ 
        "json_data" : {
            "data" : data
        },
            "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "checkbox", "ui" ]
        }).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { alert(data.rslt.obj.data("id"));   });
},"json");
```